# How do you set a "score" of the data?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, feature-selection

My data is like this

```
grid  average_2bhk  average_3bhk  conf_2bhk   conf_3bhk

210    900$          1200$           0.5         0.4
213    1012$         1360$           0.4         0.8
215    922$          1500$           0.4         0.2
```

grid is the id, we are giving to a place and average_1bhk, 2bhk is the average rent per room in that area. Conf_1bhk, 2_bhk is the number we have given according to the percentage of houses available in that area compared to other houses.

Now my question is how I can make a "score" column, which can say which grid is the most expensive  among all those, I tried using normal multiplication but that doesn't give any implication.

My professor told me to think for myself, but I have totally burned out.
Any advice would be great.

You can even tell any source where I can read about these topics, so I can think something.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Cross Validated. What is "score"? Did you do any research or googling as to how to approach the problem? At least add your effort. That would be appreciable.

Comment: Hello, I have researched but not enough to share it here. The score should be a column which signifies the grid value with the prices and the confidence that we have of the prices.

Comment: truth to be told, even I am confused about it and just a need a bit of direction where to search about it.

Comment: "Think for yourself" is great advice.  Begin by considering what *you* mean by "most expensive."  Because the meaning could (and is likely to) vary from person to person, depending on how much they value the various amenities, it's not something we or your professor can tell you.